# SwiftUI: Force View to use light or dark mode

Tags: swiftui, ios-darkmode

Is it possible in SwiftUI to force a `View` to use light or dark mode — like `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` in [UIKit](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-force-a-view-controller-to-use-light-or-dark-mode) does?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**`.colorScheme()` [is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/colorscheme(_:))** does not work with the background well.

`.preferredColorScheme()` is the way now. Does the job with the background too.

```swift
TestView1()
   .preferredColorScheme(.dark)

TestView2()
   .preferredColorScheme(.light)
```

[Developer docs for `.preferredColorScheme()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/preferredcolorscheme(_:))

Comment: In my case: `Text().background(.regularMaterial).preferredColorScheme(.dark)` did not work, but `Text().background(.regularMaterial).colorScheme(.dark)` did. That said, setting using `preferredColorScheme` higher up did work so 

Comment: If we want to change the color scheme just to a view and not the entire presentation the `preferredColorScheme` will not help. Instead we can use `.environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)`

Comment: Busata's comment provides the correct answer for changing the `colorScheme` of a particular `View`, rather than the entire app.

Answer (score 5):

Use .colorScheme modifier, like

```
TestView1()
   .colorScheme(.dark)

TestView2()
   .colorScheme(.light)
```